# Getting this error when running Magento 1.6.1 on Wampserver 2.2

Tags: magento, wampserver

I'm getting this error after having installed Magento 1.6.1 and wampserver 2.2 (64 bit)

The magento index/homepage wil1 display Ok but when i try and access the admin back-end I get the following error ??

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in C:\vhosts\perform-play\magento\lib\Varien\Http\Adapter\Curl.php on line 52

OS Windows 7 64bit

Any Ideas , I've unistalled and re-installed the wampserver ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Wampserver 2.2 installed yet, but in 2.0 I need to enable Curl support by going to PHP->PHP Extensions->php_curl in the Aestan tray menu.

(I suspect I'll be doing a Wampserver 2.2 and Magento 1.6.x install myself in the near future!)

Comment: Thanks , you are right , I have just dicovered this and was about to post an answer. Many thanks for your swift reponse.

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem on Wamp and XAMPP., nearly give up.
Finally find the solution, Magento 1.6 can not work properly with WAMP 2.1 and XMAPP 1.7, I guess it caused by Mysql version, not sure. 
but after I change WAMP to 2.0 i, everything is fine. Magento 1.6 is running well.
Download WAMP2.0i : http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.0/WampServer2.0i.exe/download

I failed to install it on Chrome, but success on firefox.

Good Luck.